# local variable referenced before assignment in tkinter

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

In tkinter while getting value of radiobutton and storing it in variable name gen. It is showing error as mentioned in title.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9ZqI.png)

[This is sql query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBvGR.png)

Comment: Please read how to make a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

need more code snippet for better understanding, but
make sure you have placeholder for variable if your function returns value
either put else statement, or initialize variable before assigning values

```
gen = ""  
if v.get() == 1:
    gen  = "Male"
if v.get() == 2:
    gen = "Female"
```

Comment: can just use `elif v.get()` to improve performance since it won't bother checking the second condition if the first condition already was True

Answer (score 0):

Hello Friend i think that its resolve with the next code, because require the keyword global, this expose the variable how to variable global in all the application.

```
if v.get() == 1:
  global get
  gen = "Male"
if v.get() == 2:
  global get
  gen = "Female"`
```

Comment: why are You setting `get` as a global? it is a function (that is global already)

Comment: Didn't you mean `global gen`?

Comment: its correct , global can bu used in functions , i imagine that your code its within of the one function, if not i dont know because has a error :(